# Linking two Scroller containers Flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Is there a way to link two Scroller containers in Adobe Flex? As in, when one scroller is modified, the same modifications will be reflected in a second scrolling container?

What I am trying to do is have an image and label on different areas of the screen that are swipable, and when they are swiped/changed I want the same change to be reflected in the other Scroller container.

Here is my initial Scroller container with images that the label Scroller container should correspond to:

```
<s:Scroller id="imageViewer" includeIn="startState" x="183" y="436" width="110"
                    height="70" depth="2" scrollSnappingMode="leadingEdge"> 
    <s:HGroup id="imageGroup" gap="0" width="110" height="70">
        <s:Image id="ICV1234" width="110" height="70" source="assets/ICV-1234.png" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:Image id="ICV4321" width="110" height="70" source="assets/ICV-4321.png" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:Image id="ICV5678" width="110" height="70" source="assets/ICV-5678.png" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        <s:Image id="ICV8765" width="110" height="70" source="assets/ICV-8765.png" verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:HGroup> 
</s:Scroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Actionscript listener for Event.ENTER_FRAME and on every frame you can sync the two scroll containers. You might be able to bind the scroll position to both containers, but I   do not know exactly if this might be possible with the components you are using.

Comment: I'll look into that and get back. Also, I updated flex to 4.6 this morning - which has the functionality built into Scroller that I was emulating with the custom SnapScroller. I have edited my post to reflect that changes from 4.5 -> 4.6

Comment: I added an enterFrame listener to the third image within the Scroller, but it seems to be constantly firing even when the third image isn't in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the scroll values of one of the scrollers to the other.

For example:

```
<s:Scroller id="scroller1">...</s:Scroller>
<s:Scroller id="scroller2" verticalScrollPosition="{scroller1.verticalScrollPosition}">...</s:Scroller>
```